# Avoid loop in computing running average/statistics over a column

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, loops

I would like to speed up the following (PostgreSQL) code, and I speculate it would help by getting rid of (some of) the loops, but I do not see a way to do that. Any suggestion on speed-up is welcomed. Thanks in advance!

The code computes some statistics (mean, slope) for each columns at different portions. The portion is determined by a sliding time window (say of 60mins). So the code below

- loops through different columns which I am interested in computing their statistics
- for each column, I sequentially move my time window and compute the statistics of the values in that window.

  ```
  for col_name in ..... a list of column names
  truncate small_table;           -- where statistics are temporarily stored
  for cur in select time from big_table loop
      execute 'select regr_slope('|| col_name ||', time) as slope,'
          || ' avg(' || col_name || ') as mean'
          || ' from big_table where'
          || ' time <=' || cur.time
          || ' and time >=' || cur.time-60
          into result;

      execute 'insert into small_table values($1,$2,$3)'
          using cur.time, result.slope, result.mean;
  end loop;

  execute 'update big_table set '
      || col_name || '_slope = small_table.slope, '
      || col_name || '_mean = small_table.mean '
      || ' where big_table.time=small_table.time';
  end loop;
  ```

`small_table`, where results are temporarily stored, is introduced to avoid multiple updates on the `big_table`.

`small_table` and `big_table` have the same structure, but the small table has much less rows.
Columns of the two tables are 
`time | field_1 | field_2 | field_1_slope | field_1_mean | field_2_slope | field_2_mean`

There are actually quite a few columns (~50), which maybe another factor of slowdown?

Comment: Does big_table have an index on the time column?

Comment: Are there fixed time intervals between data points, or random?

Comment: The time intervals are random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generate the following pattern of SQL dynamically, you can at least perform all this in one query. I'm not sure whether it will perform any better, though (obviously you need to loop through all the columns and add those in). I'd test the performance before I worry about building the SQL in code.

```
Update
    big_table b
Set
    field1_slope = x.field1_slope,
    field1_mean = x.field1_mean,
    field2_slope = x.field2_slope,
    field2_mean = x.field2_mean
From (
    Select
        b1.time,
        regr_slope(b2.field1, b2.time) field1_slope,
        avg(b2.field1) field1_mean,
        regr_slope(b2.field2, b2.time) field2_slope,
        avg(b2.field2) field2_mean
    From
        big_table b1
            Inner Join
        big_table b2
            On b2.time >= b1.time and b2.time < b1.time + 60
    Group By
        b1.time
    ) x
Where
    b.time = x.time;
```

I'm not overly familiar with PostgreSQL, there may be a way to eliminate one of the references to big table.

[Example SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/24350/1)

[Another way with cursors](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2e46e/1)

Comment: This works perfectly -- the combination of inner join, group by and explicit assignment. Thank you!